# Moving the whole page to left and then right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am looking for this kind of [template](http://www.richmediagallery.com/detailPage?id=8040) . Moving the page to left and then page to right. Can anyone tell me how can i make this or is there any javascript example similar to this.

Comment: setting the `margin` property on `html, body`

Comment: what do you mean by setting the margin property. If you click on the panel you will see entire page moving to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two `<div>`s, put them next to each other, make them take up the whole window, and change them as needed.

HTML:

```
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.left {
    background-color: green;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: width 1s;
    width: 0;
}

.left.active {
    width: 200px;
}

.right {
    background-color: red;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: left 1s;
}

.right.active {
    left: 200px;
}
```

JS (width jQuery):

```
$('.right').on('click', function() {
    $('.left').toggleClass('active');
    $('.right').toggleClass('active');
});
```

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyr183v3/).

Comment: I move to move the whole page

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to animate smooth on all devices you should use css transitions and transforms. Hiding and showing would be as basic as toggling a class then.

[The example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pulges/9L6tta9q/2/)

```
<style media="screen">
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .menu {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100px;
    background: #ABC;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  .content {
    transition: transform 0.3s;
  }

  .active .menu {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  .active .content {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
</style>

<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu">
        My menu
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        My content
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector('.toggle').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector('.wrapper').classList.toggle("active");
  });
</script>
```

NB! Supported from IE10. IE 9 will support without the animation and you probably should add the needed -ms-, -webkit-, -moz-, etc prefixes to support the older browsers if needed for transition and transform properties.

Also I advise not animating body or html with this method and put the content of page in the wrapper (in .content in the examples case). Moving body and html directly may lead to unpleasant surprises later.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how it is not working (are you clicking the toggle button), what browser are you using (regarding the needed prefixes and classList.toggle command)?

Answer (score 0):

Using [.toggle(effect,options,duration)](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to moving the page to left to right.

```
// Set the effect type
        var effect = 'slide';

        // Set the options for the effect type chosen
        var options = { direction: 'right' };

        // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
        var duration = 700;

        $('#Id').toggle(effect, options, duration);
```

Taken via this [link](https://jquerytipsntricks.wordpress.com/2013/07/21/slide-toggle-from-right-to-left-and-left-to-right-using-jquery-ui/)